# Pygame sound keeps repeating

Tags: pygame, python-3.6

I am trying to play a sound at the end of a game when there is a lose. Previously this code below worked with Python 3.5 but it would abort after it played the sound. I upgraded to python 3.6 and now it just keeps on repeating. How can I play the sound until the end?

```
import pygame
def sound():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('womp.wav')
    while True:
        sound1.play(0)
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while True` is an endless loop:

> ```py
> while True:
>    sound1.play(0)
> ```

The sound will be played continuously.

Use [`get_length()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.get_length) to get the length of the sound in seconds. And wait till the sound has end:
(The argument to [`pygame.time.wait()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.wait) is in milliseconds)

```py
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
my_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('womp.wav')
my_sound.play(0)
pygame.time.wait(int(my_sound.get_length() * 1000))
```

Alternatively you can test if any sound is being mixed by [`pygame.mixer.get_busy()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html). Run a loop as long a sound is mixed:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
my_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('womp.wav')
my_sound.play(0)
    
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    clock.tick(10)
    pygame.event.poll()
```

Comment: @ColorfulCodes That seems to be a miracle. Does the file contain the same sound sequence multiple times?

Comment: Hmm..never mind, I copied your code verbatim and it worked. I still had the while statement. Thank you!